# Send POST data through PHP from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, header

Short:
Is there a way to send POST data from a intermediate PHP page to another resultant page?

Long:
I have a page, let's say `A.php` where a form is present. The data is filled in the form, and send through POST to another page `B.php`

`B.php` checks the value and finds that the value entered is not correct (form validation). We redirect back to `A.php` with message "Invalid"

Right now I am sending data like this:

```
header("Location:A.php?msg=Invalid");
```

But I want to hide the msg part in URL from the user, by sending it in POST method or so.

I am not forced to use any particular method. This is just a project I am working on. So, please enlighten me.

So far I came to know that there is no way we can do that using `header` in PHP.

Comment: you could use sessions .

Comment: you could send it to 'invalid.php' which would process what you want (tell the user it is invalid), then send to 'A.php' with a "Continue" button - - not 'pretty', but you said any method....   A better way would be through JS - you could send an ajax form via Post.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to always post back to the same page. If there is an error you can then just display it without needing to redirect.

If there is no error then redirect to a results/response page.

The advantages of this are:

1. No need to send data that may be private through a redirect
2. If there was an error then refreshing the POST will continue to fail and will continue to only show the error message and allow the user to correct their mistake
3. If there was no error then the redirect will remove the POST operation and replace it with a new GET operation.
4. Refreshing the result page will not produce another POST operation, which might cause a problem with your data/database.

Example of what happens:

- So first the browser sends a GET request for `a.php`.
- On Form submission the browser sends a POST request for `a.php`.
- If the code for `a.php` detects an error it just re-renders the same page with the form tags filled in with the POST values.
- If the code for `a.php` does not detect an error then it does whatever it needs to do to save the data and then sends a redirect request for `b.php`.
- The browser sends a GET request for `b.php` and removes the `a.php` from its history.
- `b.php` displays some kind of thank you note or confirmation.